# What are those big plates on both sides of the steam engine?

Tags: engine

I would like to know what are those two big plates on both sides of this engine:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are [Smoke deflectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_deflectors). From Wikipedia:

...designed to lift smoke away from the locomotive at speed so that the driver has better visibility...